# Asus Tablet Model K01A Device Driver Not Found

Tags: windows-7, drivers, android, device-manager

I am trying to connect my Asus K01A tablet device to eclipse for Android development - Device's not visible for eclipse. In my computer's devices manager I see the driver is missing for the device (see the pic).

But there is another entry in devices manager - Portable Devices where driver is installed.

Well, I tried to download drivers from asus but none helped. Any assistance appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a conversation with ASUS is in order to get the required driver.

Comment: Did you try manually selecting the inf files and installing the driver for ADB ?

Comment: @HackToHell no, how is the procedure? - Because I tried it with another computer and eclipse idnetified the device. This means I have the necessary driver files.